# Instantiating a metaclass in python

Tags: python, metaclass

I wrote a class in python which inherits from `type` . I thought that this was the only requirement for a class so as to be called as a metaclass but had not defined a `__new__` method for it. But on instantiating with this new class as the metaclass I got an error stating the below :

```
TypeError: type.__new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

The following is my code  :

```
class a(type) :
    pass 
c= a()
```

Now when the class statement is being processed , that the `__new__` method of `type` is being called is my assumption. This is because the default metaclass of all classes in python is `type` .

Now when I am instantiating the class `a` , which I have assumed to be a metaclass under the assumption that any class inheriting from (`type`) is a metaclass , isn't it the same as creating a class ? Why should this not result in `type.__new__` being called with correct arguments ?

Comment: Maybe there is a x-y problem going on here. Normally the need for metaclasses arise naturally if we have a problem that will actually need then. And in this case, we will have a good idea of what they are - that does not seem to be the case.
What it is that you want to achieve with your metaclass?

Answer (score 6):

This does not work:

```
class a(type) :
    pass 
c = a()
```

...for the same reason for which this does not work:

```
c = type()
```

In the end, both do the same.

To use it as a metaclass, do this:

```
>>> class Class(metaclass=a):
...     pass
...
>>> Class
<class '__main__.Class'>
>>> type(Class)
<class '__main__.a'>
```

You could also instantiate the class directly, as you tried, but you have to provide the correct arguments:

```
AnotherClass = type('AnotherClass', (), {})

YetAnotherClass = a('YetAnotherClass', (), {})
```

Comment: @zvzone : In the second example here , you are calling the __init__ of the type class which is implicitly calling up the __new__ method right ?

Comment: @itpdusra `__init__` does not call `__new__`. When an instance is constructed, `__new__` is called first and then `__init__` is called. `__new__` creates a new instance and `__init__` initializes it. In other words, result of `__new__` is passed to `__init__` as `self`. See [Python doc on `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) for more details.

Comment: Understood that , what I wanted to be sure of is whether with the second line of instantiation you are calling the constructor of the metaclass

Comment: @itpdusra I see. The metaclass constructor is called after the last line of class definition, i.e. after `class Class(metaclass=a):` and `pass`. Try creating a metaclass with `print`s in `__new__` and `__init__` and then see when they are printed.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to you not respecting `type`'s signature.

Inheriting from `type` is indeed *enough* for a class to be used as a metaclass, but the thing is you actually have to *use* it as a metaclass.

`type` itself has "two working modes:  if called with *3* positional arguments, it creates a *new* class. And then *type* is the metaclass of that class. If called with *1* positional argument, it creates no new class or object at all - instead, it just returns that object's class.

But it makes no sense calling `type` with *no* arguments at all. And the arguments in the modes above are not optional. So, you will get a `TypeError` if your try to call type with no arguments at all - and that is not  a "TypeError because something went wrong with the type class" - it is a "TypeError because your call did not match the callable signature".

When you inherit from `type` and change nothing, you class will behave exactly the same as the original `type`: you can call it with either *one* or *three* positional arguments, and the code responsible for working in either mode lies in `type.__new__`.

Now, if you want to use your class as a metaclass, you can indeed call it, but in the three argument form: you ass it the new class name, its bases and its attributes - which can actually be all empty, but you have to pass a string, a tuple and a dictionary as these three arguments:

```
class A(type): pass

myclass = A("", (), {})
```

And now, `A` is working as the metaclass for `myclass`:

```
In [16]: type(myclass)                                                                                   
Out[16]: __main__.A
```

However, whenever one defines a metaclass it is more usual to use it with the `metaclass=` named argument when declaring a class body:

```
In [17]: class  MyOtherClass(metaclass=A): 
    ...:     pass 
    ...:                                                                                                 

In [18]: type(MyOtherClass)                                                                              
Out[18]: __main__.A
```

Python's runtime will then compile this class body, and when the bytecod for it is executed, it will make the call to your metaclass' `__new__` (and then `__init__`, and before that its `__prepare__`) method, so that it works as a metaclass.

So, just in case it is not clear: when you derive a class from `type` intending to use it as a metaclass, there is no need to further instantiate it to say that "it is now a metaclass". A subclass of type already can be a metaclass, and its *instances* will be classes, that will have it as a metaclass.